# Libgdx texture on key input too fast

Tags: java, input, libgdx, textures

I want to draw a texture when I press a key. I'm using isKeyJustPressed() method and because of this , the texture appears and dissapears really fast. How can I slow it down a bit, so I can see it appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you drawing the texture like this?

```
public void render() {
    ...
    batch.begin();
    ...
    if(isKeyJustPressed...) {
        texture.draw()...
    }
    ...
    batch.end();
    ...
}
```

If so your texture will be drawn only for just one frame.

If this is the problem:

```
float timeRemaining = 0f; // in seconds
public void render() {
    ...
    batch.begin();
    ...
    if(isKeyJustPressed...) {
        timeRemaining = 5; // will show the texture for 5 seconds
    }
    if (timeRemaining>0) {
        timeRemaining -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        texture.draw()...
    }
    ...
    batch.end();
    ...
}
```

Also I would highly suggest that you go through this tutorials before jumping into making games.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks. Indeed , I jumped into making games before I was prepared. I'll take the time to study!

Comment: @Ryncops When I started making games, I jumped right into coding just like you did. It is okay if you do. And also if you decide to study. Just don't lose your ambition while studying.